# Windows 10 WSL over Remote PowerShell or SSH

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-connection, wsl2

When logged into a Windows 10 computer directly, WSL-2 works without any issue.  I can simply run `wsl` from PowerShell, both elevated and not elevated.  The prompt simply changes to the Linux prompt.

However, when remoting in to the same computer with the same credentials , either via RemotePowerShell or OpenSSH without any issue, when I run `wsl` from the prompt I get the error `Access is denied.`

Is it possible to use WSL on Windows 10 over a remote connection?

Comment: You ne a VPN connection with access to the local IP range from a remote location. IPsec works fine for this (I have it running here).

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are receiving the message when first trying to connect via PS Remoting/SSH or when trying to open WSL once connected?

Comment: @John I am already on VPN, otherwise I would not be able to connect to these machines at all.

Comment: @JG7  I can connect via PS Remoting/SSH without any issue.  Shell connected with either method are elevated (admin).  I'll clarify the OP.

Comment: WSL works when connecting to same computer with RemoteDesktop (RDP) and then opening in either an elevated or non-elevated PowerShell.